# Restore by SQL-Script / Error at '+'

Tags: string, syntax-error, sql-server-2014, database-restore

I am currently working on a full restore SQL-script and I have following Problem: While restoring you have to decide where the mdf, ndf and ldf - files of the database should be stored. To achieve that I use `WITH MOVE`. If I insert the path by myself it works just fine.

The problem comes up when I start using string-variables instead of the actual path (for easier use). It says that there is something wrong near `+`, but I can't figure out what it is. So my question is, what is it?

```
RESTORE DATABASE Test_EMPI                            --name of the database
FROM DISK = @EMPIBackupFileLocation                   --works just fine
WITH MOVE '5_47_4403_Official_GER_EMPI' TO @RestoreFileLocation + '\' + @EMPIName + '1.mdf',  --doesnt work
MOVE 'MV_TABLES' TO 'C:\Program Files\....\DATA\Test_EMPI2.NDF',    --also works
...........
```

Executing my script I get the Error: `Incorrect syntax near '+'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
DECLARE @destination VARCHAR(1000) = @RestoreFileLocation + '\' + @EMPIName + '1.mdf'

RESTORE DATABASE Test_EMPI --name of the database
FROM DISK = @EMPIBackupFileLocation --works just fine
WITH MOVE '5_47_4403_Official_GER_EMPI' TO @destination, 
MOVE 'MV_TABLES' TO 'C:\Program Files\....\DATA\Test_EMPI2.NDF', --also works
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, it works this way!